# org-mode: Prevent org-src from restoring window configuration after editing

Tags: org-mode

When editing org-src blocks, I sometimes go to other buffers while editing but whenever I close; it restores the window configuration before editing the block which is a minor annoyance when you need to find an existing buffer.

I checked out org-src.el and this is my hack.

```
        (defun fn/org-src-inhibit-save-window-configuration ()
                 "Disable org-src from saving the window configuration"
                 ;; HACK: This uses an internal variable, might be unstable
                 (setq org-src--saved-temp-window-config nil))

               (add-hook 'org-src-mode-hook #'fn/org-src-inhibit-save-window-configuration)
```

Sadly, this is touches on a private variable so my question is there a correct way of doing this?

Comment: I found I had to slightly modify your function to make it work for me, by wrapping the function body in `(with-current-buffer (marker-buffer org-src--beg-marker) ...)`. I agree there should be a built-in option for this.

Answer (score 2):

If the first argument (labeled `CONTEXT`) to `org-edit-src-code` is `'save`, then the window configuration is *not* saved.  Try evaluating `(org-edit-src-code 'save)`.  Also, take a look at that function with `M-x find-function RET org-edit-src-code RET`. See where the first couple of lines of code say `(unless (eq context 'save) (setq org-edit-src-saved-temp-window-config (current-window-configuration)))`.

See also the optional argument to `org-edit-src-exit` -- i.e., similar as above -- if it is `'save`, then no restoration of window configuration occurs even though the variable `org-src--saved-temp-window-config` may contain a saved window configuration. To see the function, type `M-x find-function RET org-edit-src-exit RET` -- the relevant portion is at the tail end of said function.

Comment: My `org-edit-src-code` does not have a `context` arguments? Is it `org-src-switch-to-buffer`? My current `org-version` is `8.3.5`. What I did find was only two points where `org-src--saved-temp-window-config` was being modified and those belong to `org-edit-src-exit`  and `org-edit-src-code`.

Comment: Unfortunately, your version (which admittedly is the latest stable release) does not have a way for a user to turn off the feature.  You would need to comment out line 396 of `org-src.el` and then `M-x byte-compile-file`.  Essentially, you are commenting out:  `(setq org-src--saved-temp-window-config (current-window-configuration))`.  The version that I tested was the one that comes with the latest stable public release of Emacs 24.5.1, and `org-mode` version 8.2.10 is bundled with it.  You could also add features to make it optional (like previous versions), instead of commenting it out.